# Custom GSON parser exclude object instances based on property value

Tags: android, json, gson

When parsing JSON in Android using the GSON parser, I'd like to implement a rule that will exclude any objects from being created based on property value. For example:

```
{"people": [
    {"first_name": "Bob"},
    {"first_name": "Bob", "last_name": "Loblaw"}]}
```

I want to exclude the first person object because it doesn't have a last name property.

Is this possible at parse time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with `JsonDeserializer`.

Suppose you would have POJOs like

```
public class Response {
   @Getter
   private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
public class Person {
   @Getter @Setter
   private String first_name, last_name;
}
```

Creating `JsonDeserializer` like

```
public class PersonResponseDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Response> {
   // Create a new gson to make the default parsing for response object
   private final Gson gson = new Gson();

   @Override
   public Response deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT
         , JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
      Response r = gson.fromJson(json, typeOfT);
      // Remove all persons from R that have last name null
      r.getPeople().removeAll(
            r.getPeople().stream().filter( p -> p.getLast_name() == null )
             .collect(Collectors.toSet())
      );
      return r;
   }
}
```

could then be used like

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Response.class, new PersonResponseDeserializer())
        .create();
Response r = gson.fromJson(s, Response.class);
```

So this is if it is required to be done at the parse time. Maybe it is otherwise better to loop the `People` after parsing and exclude `Person`s without last name then.

Comment: Good answer, and as close as I'm going to get here. Think I'm going to clean the data after parsing at this point.